# Couldn't find package libapache2-mod-wsgi

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, apt

I have developed a website in Django, and now it must go into production. This i want to do with mod_wsgi and apache2. Unfortunately i get the error 'Couldn't find package libapache2-mod-wsgi' when running the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

I am using apache2 on ubuntu server kermic(9.10).

I will enter my sources.list also:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main
```

Does somebody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On my Ubuntu box:

```
apt-cache search libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

says

```
libapache2-mod-wsgi - Python WSGI adapter module for Apache
```

So the package is obviously there. It's in the universe repository (as per [package details](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libapache2-mod-wsgi)). Try to update your package list with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run again

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Comment: thank you. after added some extra sources(see: http://pastebin.be/22984) and run sudo apt-get update it worked

Answer (score 32):

On newer linux ditro `libapache2-mod-wsgi` may not be available as it relates to none existing dependencies like `Python 2`
Try

```sh
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Answer (score 5):

For an updated version of this question you should type the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to enable (uncomment) the Universe repositories. The Universe repos aren't usually enabled by default, and that's where libapache2-mod-wsgi lives.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libapache2-mod-wsgi

Once you've uncommented the Universe lines, run another apt-get update, then you should be able to install the package.

Comment: Josh, where would you uncomment that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
su
```

or

```
sudo su
```

And next:

```
cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
```

And

```
systemctl restart apache2
```